# Parse serialized Laravel cache data with Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json, laravel, redis

I'm using Laravel's cache feature to store keys in Redis. The key is stored as an array which Laravel's cache automatically serializes and unserializes into something like this:

```
"s:18:\"[\"bob\",\"dave\"]\";"
```

In PHP Laravel handles the parsing, but I need to access the data from Javascript. I am using the `ioredis` package in node. Everything works fine except for unserializing the data.

```
var Redis = require('ioredis');
var rediscache = new Redis();
rediscache.get("mykey", function (err, result) {
    //Attempt to parse?
    result = JSON.parse(result);
}
```

The key is fetched correctly, but is stuck as a string. I tried `JSON.parse` but this throws an error, I suppose because the format is wrong.

```
Unexpected token s at Object.parse (native)
```

How can it be correctly unserialised? I ideally want to get it as a Javascript array so a value can be altered, then re-serialised and saved back to Redis.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is a serialized string which contains a JSON string.

You can use a library if you don't want to write it yourself: https://github.com/naholyr/js-php-unserialize

After that, you'll have a JSON string, which you can then parse.

Comment: Great, that works really well. Any ideas though on how to re-serialize it for saving in the Laravel format? This package only lets you unserialise.

Comment: The serialization itself is not difficult to make yourself. Doing a quick Google, I've found that there's a library that already (most likely) does the job: https://github.com/joesonw/node-php-serialization.